# Yarn error after FINISHING stage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hpc

I am very new to yarn. I try to run an application code in a yarn cluster. When I start the cluster it seems everything is OK and I can see the ACCEPTED AND RUNNING stages. And eventually the state is FINISHED. However, just after that it throws an error as below.

```
16/12/01 15:04:30 INFO Client: Application report for application_1480601004675_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
...

16/12/01 15:15:38 INFO Client: Application report for application_1480601004675_0001 (state: RUNNING)
16/12/01 15:15:39 INFO Client: Application report for application_1480601004675_0001 (state: FINISHED)
16/12/01 15:15:39 INFO Client: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1480601004675_0001



Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1480601004675_0001 finished with failed status
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:855)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:881)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My spark configuration is `.setMaster("yarn-cluster")`. In addition, if I set it as `.setMaster("yarn-client")` an error is thrown regarding hadoop configurations and it even does not pass to RUNNING state.

I am aware that this might not be that informative. But could someone has an idea from where the error stem from? Last, the same jar file works when I run it in a node with local[*] configuration.

Comment: Why don't you just inspect the YARN logs instead of guessing? Open the YARN GUI, or use plain old command lines i.e. `yarn application -status application_1480601004675_0001`  then `yarn logs -applicationId application_1480601004675_0001 | more` *(beware, verbous stuff ahead...)*

Comment: There is a specific page in Spark online documentation for setting up Spark-on-YARN. If you use the Spark run-time deployed with a distro (Cloudera, Horton etc.) it should work out-of-the-box. Otherwise you must update `spark-env-sh` with `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf` and `export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client` (typical Horton setup) or `export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop` (typical Cloudera setup) or the like. Then you must update `spark-defaults.conf` to reference Hadoop deps in `spark.driver.extraClassPath`, `spark.driver.extraLibraryPath` etc